# auto complete text boxes in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Ok i have found a solution regarding my problem. I have three text boxes in my jsp page, when i am entering any data on first text box then control is going to `get.jsp`  to retrieve data from database and is filling 2nd text box. But I want that data will go from first and second text boxes at a time to `get.jsp` to auto fill 3rd text box , but i was trying but data was going individually from either 1st or 2nd text boxes.

----auto.jsp----------

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<html>
<head>  
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  
var xmlHttp  
var xmlHttp
function showState(str){ 
if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined"){
xmlHttp= new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
   else if (window.ActiveXObject){
xmlHttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
if (xmlHttp==null){
alert ("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
return
} 
var url="get.jsp";//goes to get.jsp
url += "?count=" +str;
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}
function stateChange(){   
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
document.getElementById("country").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;  
}   
}   
</script>  
</head>  
 <body>  
 <input id="name" type="text" name="name" onkeyup="showState(this.value)">
<br>  
<div id='country'>  
</div>  
</body> 
</html>
```

--------get.jsp-------------

```
<%@page language="java" import ="java.sql.*" %>  
 <%  
 String name=request.getParameter("count");  
 String buffer="<div>";  
 //Got value from database 


while(rs.next()){
buffer=buffer+rs.getString(2)+"<br>";  
}  
buffer=buffer+"</div>";  
response.getWriter().println(buffer);  
%>
```

Here by request.getParameter("count"); I am getting only one text box value, but how can i get multiple value from auto.jsp by entering data in first and second text boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the showState() function on your onkeyup and in the javascript function append the textbox's value.

```
var url="get.jsp";//goes to get.jsp
url += "?count=" +document.getElementById(<first textbox's id>).value;
url += "&secondVal="+document.getElementById(<second textbox's id>).value;
```

and you can get the value like you did

```
String secondVal=request.getParameter("secondVal");
```

Comment: thanks for reply.I have given first text box id as textbox1 and 2nd text box id as textbox2 but it showing error in function stateChange(){   
if (xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){   
document.getElementById("country").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;  
}   
}                                                                    i have written like this: var url="get.jsp";//goes to get.jsp
url += "?count=" +document.getElementById(<textbox1>);
url += "&secondVal="+document.getElementById(<textbox2>); Like this?

Comment: The <xyz> means replace this with the correct name:) you should be giving like this `document.getElementById("textbox1");` and `document.getElementById("textbox2");`

Comment: ok..but still not working,text boxes names should be same? <input id="name" type="text" name="name" id="textbox" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/>
     <input id="name" type="text" name="name" id="textbox2" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/>

Comment: No, you should give different ids, actually the id has to be unique in the document. You may have to give like this `<input id="textbox1" type="text" name="name" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/> <input id="textbox2" type="text" name="secondVal" onkeyup="showState(this.value)"/>` The javascript's getElementById will look for the id in id="textbox1" and the request.getParameter will look for the name as in name="secondVal"

Comment: ok, i did it..but output showing [object HTMLInputElement] for first text box and  [object HTMLInputElement] for 2nd text box, but entered value is not displaying in get.jsp

Comment: My bad, forgot to add the .`value` to them like  `document.getElementById("textbox1").value;` and `document.getElementById("textbox2").value;`

Comment: worked like a charm...:) thanks a lot prajeesh, similarly if i want many values i will add similarly as you added 2nd text box, right?

Comment: hi i faced another problem,when i am entering value in first textbox then automatically it is going to get.jsp to fetch data..that's fine, but it is creating a new get.jsp means new text box. How can i avoid it? so multiple text boxes are appearing but actually two textboxes should appear.

Comment: In your original post, `document.getElementById("country").innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;`  should replace the current content inside the div with the latest one. Check your get.jsp whether it is creating multiple textboxes in any single request.

Comment: when i am entering any data in first and second textbox then i am seeing data on 3rd textbox in that auto.jsp though 3rd textbox is present in get.jsp, but if i am keeping 3rd textbox in auto.jsp by jsp include page(get.jsp) then data is coming in 3rd textbox but an extra 3rd textbox is getting created in auto.jsp, how can avoid this extra creating 3rd textbox in auto.jsp?

Comment: You should not include the get.jsp in auto.jsp, since the data generated by get.jsp is added in the generated html file by the javascript.  get.jsp is only for generating the data that has to be added by ajax.

Comment: ok then how can i avoid this? what modification should i do in auto.jsp? please help me prajeesh